# Can I trigger a dialogue box from an applet?

Tags: java, swing, dialog, applet

I'm new to java... I'm creating an applet for a project and I wonder if an applet can launch a warning or dialogue box. If so, what would be the instruction or method?

Comment: [How to use dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer  +1 I'd use a [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features) for this one.  Very handy for short messages with a helpful icon.

Answer (score 1):

```
Frame getMyParent() {
    Container parent = getParent();
    while (!(parent instanceof Frame)) {
        parent = ((Component)parent).getParent();
    }
    return (Frame)parent;
}

public OptionsDialog(MainApplet applet, boolean modal) {
    super(null, "options", modal);
```

This will create a dialogue box. Add other features and refer to [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for more information on frames.